# Load $templateCache from file

Tags: angularjs, templates

I've been having trouble loading templates from the $templateCache.

How I put templates in $templateCache :

```
var app = angular.module('anglober', ['anglober.controllers', 'anglober.services', 'anglober.directives']).run(function ($templateCache, $http) {
    $http.get('anglober/js/invitation/invitationModal.tpl.html', {cache: $templateCache});
    $http.get('anglober/js/modal/ajaxModal.tpl.html', {cache: $templateCache});
    $http.get('anglober/js/ajaxLoader/ajaxLoader.tpl.html', {cache: $templateCache});
    $http.get('anglober/js/modal/modalContent.tpl.html', {cache: $templateCache});
    $http.get('anglober/js/modal/simpleModal.tpl.html', {cache: $templateCache});
    $http.get('anglober/js/mog/topMogs.tpl.html', {cache: $templateCache});
```

How I load them :

```
angular.module('anglober.directives').directive('topMogs', ['$templateCache', function ($templateCache) {
return {
    restrict : 'E',
    template: $templateCache.get('topMogs.tpl.html')
    //Tried this too
    // templateUrl: 'topMogs.tpl.html'
};
}]);
```

In my network browser tab, I can see the templates being loaded at page load.

However I get the following error when calling my directive :

```
One of template or templateUrl options is required.
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: You should mention the full url 'anglober/js/mog/topMogs.tpl.html'

Comment: You are creating extra work for yourself and achieving nothing. Remove all the `$http.get` from your `run` method, and just let `$templateCache` do it's job. Use `templateUrl` in your directives. What you are doing is a very odd thing to do.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. What I wanted to do is access templates files in my modules by putting only the template file name (no path). Should I put absolute path for template files in my modules anyway ? I found that a bit strange to have to put full path like this : templateUrl: pathToModule/templateFile and not templateUrl: templateFile because I put my templateFiles in the same directory as my modules js files.

Comment: What I do is run a grunt task that puts all my template files inside a JavaScript file that calls `$templateCache.add(..)`. I then use a custom naming convention. Google `grunt angular templates`

Answer (score 9):

A small addition to this old thread:

Although there are few ways to achieve your goal, the best approach for me was to add the `$templateCache` logic into each of my app's directives. This way, I could avoid using any external packages like `grunt angular-templates` (which is excellent - but kind of an overkill for my app)

```
angular.module('MyApp')
.directive('MyDirective', ['$templateCache', function($templateCache) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: $templateCache.get('MyTemplate'),
        controller: 'MyController',
        controllerAs: 'MyController'
    };
}]).run(function($templateCache, $http) {
    $http.get('templates/MyTemplate.html').then(function(response) {
        $templateCache.put('MyTemplate', response.data);
    })
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I don´t really understand why to do this. This is not loading the template in templateCache in "compilation" time, it's retrieving the template with an http call and loading it in the cache, but isn´t this what AngularJS does by default?

Comment: It can be useful if you want to overwrite default $templateCache values used by some framework e.g. for ui-grid:
$http.get("app/templates/ui-grid-filter.html").then(function(response) {
    $templateCache.put('ui-grid/ui-grid-filter', response.data);
});

Comment: This gives an error: `TypeError: $http is undefined`.

Comment: @zygimantus - Did you remember to inject the `$http` service in the `run()` dependencies?